# Duplicate entry '14612_LAYOUT_101_INSTANCE_j6uJ' for key 'IX_8D83D0CE' when browse the portal's website

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, liferay-6

I'm deploying a cluster with 2 liferay server which share a mysql database. All work perfect but yesterday morning it cannot be connected. I checked my logs and found 2 exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.constraintviolationexception could not execute jdbc batch update
```

and

```
duplicate entry '14612_LAYOUT_101_INSTANCE_j6uJ' for key 'IX_8D83D0CE'
```

I found this index is assigned for table '**resourcespermission**' but had no ideal for this exception.

I restarted both servers and the the portal worked fine. But I afaided that this error can comeback and I have no solution for it beside restarting liferay servers.

I wonder why the liferay server run batch update for the resourcespermission when I just browse the portal's website. Is this abnormal?? And can you tell me if this duplicate can come from the cluster configuration??

Thanks!

Comment: Which Liferay version?

Comment: I'm using liferay 6.0.4